# Android adds keys to non-assoc json array received from web service

Tags: android, json, httprequest, associative-array, arrays

I've run into a problem that sounds simple to solve, but isn't all that clear to me.

I receive a Json from my webservice at [this url](http://www.v-art.be/tongil/messages). You'll see that I have a JsonArray of objects named "messages":

```
{"status":"200",
"messages":[
    {"Id":"3",
     "Titel":"Test",
     "Bericht":"Test",
     "Datum":"2014-07-10 0:45:12"},
    {...}
]
}"
```

I let Android parse this received context, but it apparently the array "messages" gets converted to an assoc array somehow:

```
{"status":"200",
"messages":[
    {"2":
        {"Id":"3",
         "Titel":"Test",
         "Bericht":"Test",
         "Datum":"2014-07-10 0:45:12"}
    },
    {"3": {...}}
]
}"
```

This is how I receive the json string:

```
// appending params to url
if (params != null) {

    String urlParams = "";
    for(NameValuePair param : params) {
        urlParams += "/" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getName(), "UTF-8") + "/";
        urlParams += URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8");
    }
    url += urlParams.replace("+", "%20");

}
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

The return value is the first json above. Any idea why this is happening? I assume that Android didn't interpret the received content as a Json, therefore I don't know how the array gets turned into an assoc array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from this: `EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)`. You should use function below:

```
private static final String parseStringFromResponse(
        final HttpResponse response) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems that I whenever I post something, i find the solution myself :(
But you were right about what you said, so I'll vote for you :)
The problem was that I sliced the array on my webservice and had preserve association enabled, so yeah... Thanks anyway!